# how to export textures in FBX file

Tags: export

hi I have made a olaf model with textures and materials and I want to sell this model but I don't know to export the textures and materials in a FBX and OBJ file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: But how do other 3D models have their textures when downloaded